# Repeater binding @ serverside

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in my aspx page. The datasource for this will change for different types of call hence I cannot  do

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <tr >
       <td bgcolor="" valign="top">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>
                </td>
```

...

as the dataItem will be different. Which is the best way to do it  server side?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't that ok so long as your current datasource has an Id property?

Comment: yes it will have an id but other columns are different.

Comment: Will the DataField be different? As in, it might be PersonID this time and ProductID the next?

Comment: what about using two repeaters and bind one of them according to type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, the best way will be create interface and write adapters for every type. In repeater you gonna be work only with this interface.

Comment: I guess u r correct but i am just thinking if i could do it in a much simpler and straight forward way as i have just one day to finish and test it.

Comment: But this way will be easiest to. If you need logic to bind only one field with the same name in every datasource <%# Eval("ID")%> could really works... But if there something more complicated like different names or more then one fields to bind... your just will spend more time in bug fixing and all if/switch solving. appreciate your time, let compiler check all bugs ;)

Comment: I also have some jscript on  $(document).ready(function() which would need the repeater id or else it will fail the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<asp:Label ID="lable1" runat="server" ondatabinding="label1_ondatabinding" />
```

and manually fill data in the event handler.

```
protected void label1_ondatabinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((Label)sender).Text = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need to do it ondatabinding but something maybe onload , what would be the function signature and how could i create item template?